# Run fgrep multicore mac os x

Tags: macos, grep, multicore

I'm running this command on my Mac OS X on 8 cores:

```
for i in $(cat file1);do grep "$i" file2; done > output.txt
```

My file2 i 9 milion lines so it takes a lot of time.

Is it possible to use all the cores to do this job faster?

Comment: Try asking this on [UNIX & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Comment: Much more efficient would be to get rid of the loop and just use `grep -f file1 file2 > output.txt`.

Comment: but i would like to obtain the results in the same order  of the file1. my scritp it works but it is too slow

Answer (score 0):

You could try this `awk` instead:

```
awk 'FNR==NR {a[$0];next} {for (i in a) if ($0~i) print}' file1 file2  > output.txt
```

But the `grep` posted by `Paul R` would be faster I guess.

```
grep -f file1 file2 > output.txt
```

Comment: i know that this are more faster but i want the output in the same order of the file1 for this i used my script

Answer (score 0):

Based on http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#EXAMPLE:-Grepping-n-lines-for-m-regular-expressions

```
parallel -k parallel --pipepart --block 100M -a file2 -k grep {} :::: file1
```